# Reduce whitespace between columns in a chakra Table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, whitespace, chakra-ui

I'm creating a basic small `Table` in `chakra-ui`, however the whitespace between columns is too much for my particular use case. I've set `size="sm"` but it's still too much whitespace.

[image]

How can we achieve this? Here's a summary snippet of pseudo-code corresponding to my problem:

```
<Table size="sm">
  <Thead>
    // ...
  </Thead>
  <Tbody>
    //...
  </Tbody>
</Table>
```

Here's the full worked example in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-table-forked-ut904?file=/src/ResponsiveTable.tsx:196-344

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just to add css to override css of Table:

```
<Table size="small" className="table-tiny" />
```

and in css:

```
.table-tiny th,
.table-tiny td {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-table-forked-8683s?file=/src/ResponsiveTable.tsx

Comment: doesn't seem to work